# Adjust the generated name with XML GENERATE Function

Tags: cobol

If I have the COBOL structure like this:

(the structure should be like this because I have to convert it using `XML Generate Function`, the variable name just sample)

```
01. MyData.
02. Corp-Entity
    03. Corp-Branch1.
        04. Address.
            05. AddressLine1 PIC X(20).
            05. AddressLine2 PIC X(20).
            05. PostalCode   PIC 9(05).
        04. PIC-Entity.
            05. Address.
                06. AddressLine1 PIC X(20).
                06. AddressLine2 PIC X(20).
                06. PostalCode   PIC 9(05).
```

How to move a value in `05. AddressLine1`?

If I write this code:

```
move valueAddressLine1 to AddressLine1 
                       in Address
                       in Corp-Brach1
                       in MyData
```

But this code is valid for `06. AddressLine1`

```
move valueAddressLine1 to AddressLine1 
                       in Address
                       in PIC-Entity
```

**Error Message:**
"AddressLine1 of Address of PIC-Entity" was not a uniquely defined name.
The definition to be used could not be determined from the context.  The reference to the name was discarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pre-notes:**

- That code won't work because of the periods after the level numbers, get rid of these.
- To have a unique name you don't need the full qualification. For example the following is fine:

```
            move valueAddressLine1 to AddressLine1 
                                   in PIC-Entity
```

**Answer:**

In cases like this: "fix" the COBOL side by using a name that can be accessed uniquely, in most cases by its "parent" items and where this isn't possible like your `04 Address` by using a different name (for example `04 corp-address`) .

As you want this structure in XML you may use the `NAME` phrase as IBM's docs [XML element name and attribute name formation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_6.2.0/com.ibm.cobol62.ent.doc/PGandLR/ref/rlpsxmlge.html) says:

> In the XML documents that are generated from *identifier-2*, the XML element names and attribute names are obtained from the `NAME` phrase if specified; otherwise they are derived from the names of the data item specified by *identifier-2* and from any eligible data-names that are subordinate to *identifier-2*.

IBM's docs on [XML GENERATE statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_6.2.0/com.ibm.cobol62.ent.doc/PGandLR/ref/rlpsxmlg.html) have details on this. For the given sample and assumed 2 corp-branches:

```
           XML GENERATE variable-name
               FROM Corp-Entity
               NAME OF corp-address in corp-branch1 IS 'Address'
                       corp-address in corp-branch2 IS 'Address'
```